# App and website views show the same stats

Tags: google-analytics

I have website that has an app.
i have property which contain 2 views
one for website
and one for the application.

what I wanted:
on each view to see separate stats.

the problem is on the application view I also see the stats from the website.
on my app i am using analytics sdk, and on my website the normal universal js code.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. I'm using angularjs btw. Did you solve this?

Comment: @iamemmanouil nope, just opened a new property